# Xcode - Half view in from of another

Tags: xcode, cocoa, view, uiview, storyboard

Is there anyway to have a view that overlaps the main view, but not all of it? Just about 80/90%? I'm asking that because the designer has designed something like that:

[image]

As you see, I've one View and the main view behind. How can I implement that? And what's the best way to create a costum view, that can be reusable in the future?

Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `UIView`'s origin x like this: (for example 100px space from left)

```
view.frame = CGRectMake( 100, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height );
```

Don't forget that x and y starts from left bottom corner.

```
view.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, width, height);
```

---

> what's the best way to create a custom view, that can be reusable in
>   the future?

Add `UIView` from Objects library and then subclass it.

---

**UPDATE** (Do with animation):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        [viewOutlet setFrame:CGRectMake( 100, viewOutlet.frame.origin.y, viewOutlet.frame.size.width, viewOutlet.frame.size.height)];
    }];
```

Comment: And it's possible to do that with animation? Like I click on a button on the main view, and that panel comes from the right?

Comment: Just write the animation as you want. Check this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uiview-animations/